# how to convert csv file to xml file in c# by columns

Tags: c#, xml, csv

right now I have csv file in there it contains  Worker, Account Id, Account Code, Hierarchy, and Date column. how do I write c# code to convert csv file to xml file?

```
select new XElement("Worker",
    new XElement("Account Id", columns[0]),
    new XElement("Account Code", columns[1]),
    new XElement("Hierarchy", columns[2]),
    new XElement("Date", columns[3]),
```

For now I have code something like that, how can I make improve on that code?

Comment: That did not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could ensure the column names are the same by doing something like:

```
new XElement(columns[0].Key, columns[0].value)
```

That way you wouldn't have to continually type in every single column name, and could just use a foreach(..) block to generate it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication55
{
    class Program
    {
        const string csvFILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        const string xmlFILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader();
            DataSet ds = reader.ReadCSVFile(csvFILENAME, true);
            ds.WriteXml(xmlFILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
        }
    }
    public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a class from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302293.aspx) called XmlCsvReader You only have to specify your filepath where the csv document is located. Then you specify your root's name which is Worker and it'll take care of the rest when it's loaded. The only thing that needs to be done is to specify where you want to output it using the Save method!

```
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
   XmlCsvReader reader = new XmlCsvReader(new Uri("//yourfilepath.input.csv"), doc.NameTable); 
   reader.FirstRowHasColumnNames = true; 
   reader.RootName = "Worker"; 
   reader.RowName  = "Worker"; 
   doc.Load(reader); 
   doc.Save("output.xml");
```